# How can I automate simulations with Jupyter ?

Tags: python, automation, jupyter-notebook

I'm running learning simulations on my computer. Running simulations one after another is counter-productive since they don't last very long and do not provide enough time to focus on other things. I wrote a script to write a log, which worked fine but lacked visuals. Hence, I used PyLaTeX to generate a pdf of my results with plots, but it also lacks flexibility, in particular because of figures positionning.

Then, the inspiration was here and I thought of Jupyter. Has anyone ever experiences automating things with Jupyter ? Any ideas how I could handle this ?

Thanks !